Invalid identifier errors on foreign key statements SQL
I'm converting a database structure into SQL and I'm getting an "invalid identifier" error on all my foreign key statements. Maybe someone can help me?
Example (I also added some create statements to help answer the question):
CREATE TABLE haendler 
(
    haendlername varchar(20), 
    idh1 char, 
    idh2 char
);

CREATE TABLE fahrzeuge 
(
    marke varchar(20),
    autonummer char,
    idfa char,
    position varchar(20),
    korstenprotag char,
    status varchar(20),
    tec_ps char,
    tec_gewicht char,
    tec_sitze char,
    tec_verbrauch char
);

CREATE TABLE kunden 
(
    kundenname varchar(20),
    kundenvorname varchar(20),
    kundennummer char,
    idk char,
    adr_stadt varchar(20),
    adr_bereich char
);

CREATE TABLE mitarbeiter 
(
    mitarbeitername varchar(20),
    mitarbeitervorname varchar(20),
    mitarbeiternummer char,
    fachbereichnr char,
    filiale char,
    idm char,
    gehaltpromonat char
);

ALTER TABLE fahrzeuge
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_mitarbeiter_fahrzeuge
        FOREIGN KEY (filiale) REFERENCES mitarbeiter;

ALTER TABLE fahrzeuge
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_kunden_fahrzeuge
        FOREIGN KEY (idk) REFERENCES kunden;

ALTER TABLE autosorte
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_haendler_autosorte
        FOREIGN KEY (idh2) REFERENCES haendler;


Do the mitarbeiter, kunden and haendler tables exist?

yes they all exist and are correctly created without errors

I'd start with proper ID naming. A table called haendler should have a primary key that you either call id or haendler_id or id_haendler . And tables referencing a haendler would have a column called haendler_id or id_haendler then. Same for all other tables. Then check your constraints. They should explicitly tell which column they reference. How would a filiale reference a mitarbeiter by the way? Do you know what a foreign key is supposed to do?

You need to reference both foreign table and column, like
ALTER TABLE fahrzeuge
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_mitarbeiter_fahrzeuge
FOREIGN KEY (filiale)
REFERENCES mitarbeiter(column_name);

where column_name is the column in the foreign table.

Not true. If referenced column is omitted, the primary key is implicitly chosen.

Ok thank you, but isnt the column im referencing just the same as the foreign key itself or am i misunderstanding? Because if I do that nothing changes about these errors

@jarlh you're probably right, but I've never seen that before. Best to be explicit though, methinks, for clarity and as a service to future self :)

@EricBlacker could you add your CREATE TABLE definitions to your question?

@SeaP.You added some, i added the primary keys and unique keys seperatly because it was stated so in the question. they basically all look like this: ALTER TABLE fahrzeuge
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_fahrzeuge PRIMARY KEY (autonummer);

@EricBlacker
First thing that jumps out of the CREATE TABLE's is that there are no columns marked as PRIMARY KEY.
What database engine are you using here? MySQL, PostgreSQL ..other?

@SeaP.You i am required to use Oracle

@SeaP.You the question specifically states that I have to use an alter statement to set the primary key for each table, which i did

@EricBlacker In your first ALTER TABLE, the foreign-key is referencing another table 'mitarbeiter' which doesn't exist (you have not created that table yet).
Also, the column 'filiale' which you are trying to link between table fahrzeuge and (the missing) mitarbeiter table, doesn't exist either.

@SeaP.You am I not trying to refference a foreign key from a different table than Fahrzeuge? if it already was in Fahrzeuge then it would no longer be a foreign key. The column "filiale" exists in the tabel "Mitarbeiter" and i want it to be a foreign key for "fahrzeuge". Maybe I am completely off here, I am very inexperienced in SQL.

@EricBlacker See my updated comment.

@SeaP.You the issue is: Mitarbeiter does exist and was created without errors, i had not pasted the entire programm its simply too long, Ive added it for refference. I made Filiale a unique key of Mitarbeiter by using an ALTER statement. This key should now refference the primary key of Fahrzeuge. In general all tables and keys used in the things you see have been created.

@EricBlacker I see, but according to your CREATE TABLE of Fahrzeuge, you have not defined a PRIMARY KEY so the ALTER TABLE for creating the foreign-key can't know which column to point to. See: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-primary-key/

@SeaP.You i know that but i used the following line to set a primary key: ALTER TABLE fahrzeuge ADD CONSTRAINT pk_fahrzeuge PRIMARY KEY (autonummer), this basically does the same as just setting it during the create statement, but sadly the  task i got wants me to do it like this

It'll help if you put all your SQL commands into Pastebin (or similar) and link it here, so it is possible to run it and see the errors.

https://pastebin.com/xJpxKj73 this is the entire code

@EricBlacker Here's a version where everything except the foreign-keys work:
https://pastebin.com/HEyt5jte
Compare it to your own version.
The problem with your foreign-keys is that both columns in the relation must exist.
A foreign-key is a column on a table that points to a column in another table, so they must both be there. See: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-foreign-key/ to understand the concept.
Also SQL comments begin with '--' not '//'

Hi - can I suggest you simplify your question by providing the complete DDL (including all PKs and FKs) for just two tables: one that has an FK and the other being the table that the FK is referencing. This will make it much easier to understand and if someone provides a solution then you can apply it to all your other tables

You seem to misunderstand foreign keys completely.
Let's translate first: A haendler is a dealer, and a fahrzeug is a car (approximately). Here is a typical dealer table:
CREATE TABLE dealer
(
  id_dealer INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name      VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE dealer ADD CONSTRAINT pk_dealer PRIMARY KEY (id_dealer);

Now there are two possible relations between car and dealer:
The car is one car
The car is the one manufactured car of a certain type. It has a vehicle identification number engraved into its chassis. This means that one car is sold by one dealer. A 1:n relation (a dealer can sell many cars, a car is sold by one dealer). So the car table has an id_dealer to state which dealer a car belongs to.
CREATE TABLE car
(
  id_car                         INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name                           VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  model                          VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  vehicle_identification_number  VARCHAR2(17 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  id_dealer                      INTEGER           NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE car ADD CONSTRAINT pk_car PRIMARY KEY (id_car);
ALTER TABLE car ADD CONSTRAINT fk_car_dealer FOREIGN KEY (id_dealer) REFERENCES dealer (id_dealer);

The car is a type of a car
This means that many dealers can sell the same car. An m:n relation (a dealer can sell many cars, a car can be sold by many dealers). For this you need the car table and a bridge table to relate a dealer with a car.
CREATE TABLE car
(
  id_car                         INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name                           VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  model                          VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE car ADD CONSTRAINT pk_car PRIMARY KEY (id_car);

CREATE TABLE dealer_car
(
  id_dealer                      INTEGER           NOT NULL
  id_car                         INTEGER           NOT NULL,
  vehicle_identification_number  VARCHAR2(17 CHAR) NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE dealer_car ADD CONSTRAINT pk_dealer car PRIMARY KEY (id_dealer, id_car);
ALTER TABLE dealer_car ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dealer_car_dealer FOREIGN KEY (id_dealer) REFERENCES dealer (id_dealer);
ALTER TABLE dealer_car ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dealer_car_car FOREIGN KEY (id_car) REFERENCES car (id_car);

I hope this gets you started.
